# How can i download paho and pip on my Windows 10

Tags: pip, mqtt, ironpython, paho

I am currently programming in IronPython 2.7 and would like to integrate Paho.

Since I became IronPython 2.7, I have to download Python 2 and not Python 3.

when I get the command

```
pip install paho-mqtt
```

heard in my Windows 10 terminal

what error message appears:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1, 2020. Please update your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will end support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. Further information on Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2- support
Requirement already fulfilled: paho-mqtt in c: \ python27 \ lib \ site-packages (1.5.0)
```

has an idea what I have to do?

Comment: It's not an error, but a warning. `Requirement already satisfied` means that `paho-mqtt` is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Python you are using must be below the minimum supported version of for Python 2, and that's why you get the error.
Paho-MQTT does not work with Python versions below 2.7.9, according to their
documentation.
Try this:

1. Delete your current Python.
2. Install the newest python from their website, install it on PATH.
3. Verify that your installation was successful with cmd -> python (should show your version, i.e Python 3.8.3)
4. Install your package with cmd -> pip install paho-mqtt

Comment: i have installed the newest python 2 from their website. this is 2.7.18. i think i need python 2 because i programm with IronPython 2.7, and not with Python 3.

Comment: when i write "python --version" in my cmd window, there is coming nothing. a empty line.

Comment: when i write pip install paho-mqtt, it comes this: DEPRECATION: pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
 .....

Comment: I am not sure if it has been released yet, but they were talking about IronPython 3, which will support Python 3. You should look into it because working with Python 2 will result in lots of warnings down the road for you.